# Isn't android's Bundle functionally equivalent with a Map?

Tags: java, android, bundle

I'm looking for a way to convert a Bundle to a HashMap. I'm surprised that such a method is not in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html).

Is not the Bundle equivalent of a Map, where you have String *keys* and Object *values*? Can it be theoretically converted to a mapping? What is the way to do this?

**edit**: **Is the relation between key and value in Bundle unambiguous?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is not the Bundle equivalent of a Map, where you have String keys and Object values?

First, a `Map` does not necessarily have `String` keys.

Second, while a `Map` can hold arbitrary objects, it cannot do so in a typesafe fashion. IOW, if you want the `Map` to hold strings, integers, and so forth, you will need to keep casting the results of `get()` calls, because your `Map` would have to be `Map<String, Object>`.

Third, `Bundle` implements `Parcelable`, which is very important for Android IPC. `Map` is an interface and does not extend `Parcelable`.

> Can it be theoretically converted to a mapping?

Um, sure, though I fail to see what the benefit would be.

> What is the way to do this?

Iterate over the `keySet()` and call `get()` on the `Bundle` for each key, putting the result into a `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: Thanks, I know String is not the only type that can be used with Map, I've meant the way Bundle could be mapped. :) The benefit would be communication with non-Android-aware classes. The important thing is, is the relation between key and value in Bundle unambiguous?

Comment: @naxa: "is the relation between key and value in Bundle unambiguous?" -- I do not understand the question. If you mean "are keys unique?", the answer is "yes".

Comment: not sure if we mean the same things; does uniqueness of the key mean and guarantee that only one (retriveable) object is stored per key?

Comment: @naxa: "only one (retriveable) object is stored per key?" -- yes.

Comment: thanks; btw, I should've asked similar, subset, or superset, instead of 'equivalent' of a Map, now I see. Nevermind, you've answered my question either way.